# No script on page

Tags: javascript, html

for some reason, my javascript is not working. When I view it in Firebug, it says "no script on page" when I clearly have a javascript. My page is at http://thomaswd.com/maze/highscores/delete.php. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I don't get any such error

Comment: Place your _testcase_ into the question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A, not your own personal code debugging service.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your javascript calls on the page. For starters, all of your Deleteqry(name) calls need to have the parameters be in quotes, such as Deleteqry("name"). These types of errors will keep your javascript from running.

Answer (score 1):

When I load the page firebug shows the jquery and the bleh.js javascrpit files in the "head", and it shows their contents. Maybe firefox cached the page try closing and opening firefox or clearing your cache.

To keep the browser form caching the javascript you could do something like this, while the page is in development

```
<script src="bleh.js?<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

Its a neat trick to make the browser think its a different js file.

Comment: I can see the script in the source code, but it doesnt run

Comment: I noticed several of your onclick's are missing the closing parentheses ")".